# Simple trigonometrical equation with cosine and a constant.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm stuck at a relatively simple equation where I was simplifying like this:

$$\cos^2(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)-\sin^2(x) = 1
\iff \sin(2x)+\cos(2x) = 1$$
$$
\iff \cos(2x)+\cos(π/2+2x) = 1$$

But how to I continue? I am not getting around this constant (1). I am trying to use arccos but how does that work with this constant in the way? Online calculators only use complicated identities which won't help me in my test when we won't be allowed formula papers and similar.

Comment: Any linear combination of sines and cosines of the same argument (here $2x$) can be expressed as a single sinusoid of the same argument (here a function of the form $A\cos(2x+\phi)$ for some constants $A$ and $\phi$). Try expanding the latter function and comparing coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

Rewrite 
$$
\cos(x)^2+2\sin(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)^2=1
$$
use the trigonometric identity $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$ to get
$$
\cos(x)^2+2\sin(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)^2=\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2.
$$
Now, simplify to get
$$
2\sin(x)\cos(x)-2\sin(x)^2=0.
$$
Factoring the LHS gives
$$
2\sin(x)(\cos(x)-\sin(x))=0.
$$
Now, all you need to solve is $\sin(x)=0$ and $\cos(x)=\sin(x)$.

There is no perfect system for solving these types of equations.  In general, avoid things like $\arcsin(x)$ or $\sin(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos(x)^2}$ before you've exhausted the other options.  Also, always try to replace $1$ by $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2$ just to see if that might work.

Comment: Perfect! I was trying it with the identity you stated but never thought of splitting it up and factoring out sin(x). Thanks for the input, that really helped! :)